# Getting 0 in GroupByMonth when it returns NULL

Tags: mysql

I`m trying to get values with mysql, but it gives no 0 for specific months when there is no value for it...

I tried IFNULL but it makes same and not returning 0 for the empty month.

```
 SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(`bileti_id`),0) FROM `wp_biletistatus` WHERE
 `user_id`= 1 and `status`=1 GROUP BY MONTH(`date`) ORDER BY `date` ASC
 Limit 10
```

Here is my query as well for months which i want to get:

```
 SELECT MONTHNAME(`date`) FROM `wp_biletistatus` WHERE `user_id`= 1
 GROUP BY MONTH(`date`) ORDER BY `date` ASC Limit 10
```

Can someone help me how to get 0 for the months which has no value to count.

Comment: Provide some sample data set with your table definition

Comment: id | bileti_id |status | user_id | point |date

Answer (score 1):

the reason why you are not getting zero on months that don't have value is because simply it does not exist. You need to have a fix values or atleast a subquery which have the list of all months, example.

```
SELECT months.MonthNum,
    COUNT(a.bileti_id) 
FROM    (
    SELECT 1 AS MonthNum UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9  UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11  UNION ALL SELECT 12
    ) months
    LEFT JOIN wp_biletistatus a
        ON months.MonthNum = MONTH(a.date)
WHERE a.user_id= 1 and a.status=1 
GROUP BY months.MonthNum  
ORDER BY months.MonthNum
```

Comment: It is returning Months and Count results, But still there are no months with 0 results... And i wanted only count results with months where are results 0 as well.